# Translating "a one-day stay"

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to translate the following sentence into German:

Due to the delay, I had an unexpected one-day stay in Berlin.

(Assuming this is proper English; I am not a native speaker.)

I am considering to use the word "Tagesaufenthalt". According to my web searches, the word has at least three meanings in German:

1. A one-day stay in a hotel or a spa
2. The place where people or animals dwell during daytime
3. A building where homeless people can stay during daytime.

Furthermore, "einen Aufenthalt haben" gives some web hits, but I am not sure if these are machine-translated and might actually sound silly in German.

So my question is: Would "...hatte ich einen unerwarteten Tagesaufenthalt in..." be an appropriate translation of the sentence in question?

Comment: "einen Aufenthalt haben" is a common phrase for such situations, but it will not define how long this stay was. In you case I would use "einen längeren Aufenthalt haben" whichdoes not define the amount of time too, but with the context of traveling (and not finished the tour yet) it should work. Because I agree with the answer of convaldo, this is a context adding comment only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, "*Ich hatte einen unerwarteten Tagesaufenthalt*" would be correct, at least when the context of travelling is given.
However, another possibility would be

> "... hatte ich unerwartet einen eintägigen Aufenthalt"

I think most native speakers would use the second sentence when speaking, as it sounds more natural (at least for me).

Comment: To me, it does not sound very natural at all to use neither Tagesaufenthalt nor Aufenthalt in the translation. I would rather go for something like '..., musste ich unerwartet einen Tag in Berlin bleiben/abwarten."

Comment: The problem with jarnbjo's otherwise fine translation is that it frames the sojourn as a _Müssen_. But it was only unexpected.

Comment: One could still use jarnbjo’s translation and use “bin geblieben” instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your translation is correct, and any ambiguity in meaning resolved by the context (even if I don't remember to have encountered the homeless meaning).

The sentence sounds very formal,howver, and I consider the composite noun *Tagesaufaufenthalt* to be responsible for it. Composite nouns have their merits, but colloquially one would more likely say something like:

> ... musste (or, according to your comment, if the pleasure was more important than the delay: *konnte*) ich überraschend den restlichen Tag (or *einen Tag*) in Berlin verbringen